# Similarity between words

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

I've got the following problem:

Let's say I have this given string:

```
A = "Today, the weather is fine. The sun is shining and we'd love to go swimming. Since the water is cold, we only walk around. We love weekends."
```

The set of words in A will describe my word vector basis.

Let's say we have another set of words for which I'd like to calculate cosine similarity:

```
B = "Friday, morning, tomorrow, today, sun, moon, fun, swim"
```

I then calculate the weights of the features in the vector using point-wise mutual information. (Let's assume they are given.)

How can I calculate the similarity score between the words in B? The result should be a BxB-Matrix.

To calculate the cos-similarities, I have already done this:

```
def counter_cosine_similarity(c1, c2):
    terms = set(c1).union(c2)
    dotprod = sum(c1.get(k, 0) * c2.get(k, 0) for k in terms)
    magA = math.sqrt(sum(c1.get(k, 0)**2 for k in terms))
    magB = math.sqrt(sum(c2.get(k, 0)**2 for k in terms))
    return dotprod / (magA * magB)
```

where c1, c2 are Counter-objects.

But: My function is correct concerning the cos-calculation. But how can I calculate the similarities of every word in B? 
With the given solution, I only can calculate the similarity of a whole string / list with another string / list.

Thank you very much for any help!